# Grouping results with left and inner join with zero counts

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

I have a query like

```
SELECT 
    `campaign_question_options`.`text`, 
    COUNT(`campaign_submission_answers`.`answer`) as `count`
    FROM `campaign_questions`
    INNER JOIN `campaign_question_options` ON `campaign_question_options`.`campaign_question_id` = `campaign_questions`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `campaign_submission_answers` ON `campaign_submission_answers`.`answer` = `campaign_question_options`.`text` AND `campaign_submission_answers`.`campaign_question_id` = 1
    LEFT JOIN `campaign_submissions` ON `campaign_submissions`.`id` = `campaign_submission_answers`.`campaign_submission_id`
    LEFT JOIN `participants` ON `participants`.`id` = `campaign_submissions`.`participant_id`
WHERE 
    `campaign_questions`.`id` = 1
GROUP BY `campaign_submission_answers`.`answer` 
ORDER BY `campaign_question_options`.`index`;
```

This gives me a result set like

```
+--------------+-------+
|     text     | count |
+--------------+-------+
| 1 (positive) |   114 |
| 2            |    48 |
| 3 (neutral)  |    34 |
| 4            |     6 |
| 5 (negative) |     0 |
+--------------+-------+
```

So the problem is that I then need to filter the results further on the `participants`.`appraisee_id` column. However if I add this to the where clause I lose my zero result (since the left join returns a null row).

```
SELECT 
    `campaign_question_options`.`text`, 
    COUNT(`campaign_submission_answers`.`answer`) as `count`
FROM `campaign_questions`
INNER JOIN `campaign_question_options` ON `campaign_question_options`.`campaign_question_id` = `campaign_questions`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `campaign_submission_answers` ON `campaign_submission_answers`.`answer` = `campaign_question_options`.`text` AND `campaign_submission_answers`.`campaign_question_id` = 1
LEFT JOIN `campaign_submissions` ON `campaign_submissions`.`id` = `campaign_submission_answers`.`campaign_submission_id`
LEFT JOIN `participants` ON `participants`.`id` = `campaign_submissions`.`participant_id`
WHERE 
    `campaign_questions`.`id` = 1 AND `participants`.`appraisee_id` = 1
GROUP BY `campaign_submission_answers`.`answer` 
ORDER BY `campaign_question_options`.`index`;
```

Which returns

```
+--------------+-------+
|     text     | count |
+--------------+-------+
| 1 (positive) |    16 |
| 2            |     1 |
+--------------+-------+
```

When in fact I wish for

```
+--------------+-------+
|     text     | count |
+--------------+-------+
| 1 (positive) |    16 |
| 2            |     1 |
| 3 (neutral)  |     0 |
| 4            |     0 |
| 5 (negative) |     0 |
+--------------+-------+
```

Can anyone help me improve this query?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have created a DB dump of the structure which could be useful if any kind people wish to continue helping me on this. https://gist.github.com/simonbowen/a8316fe91c78b8464402

Comment: It's great that you've shown us your attempts, but if it was me I'd start with proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) and a desired result

Comment: @Strawberry You're right, however it doesn't let me load in the data (8000 character limit). This is the structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7e5

Comment: We don't need to see the whole thing. Just enough to be representative.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok, I have provided a fiddle with the structure, and also a dump in the comment update. I outline my expected results at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on this question, I tried attempting this query from a different angle. It seems to output the results I expect, however I am not sure if it's the most efficient way since I have had to use a subquery.

```
SELECT `campaign_question_options`.`text`, COUNT(`csa`.`answer`) FROM `campaign_questions`
INNER JOIN `campaign_question_options`  ON `campaign_question_options`.`campaign_question_id` = `campaign_questions`.`id`
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT `campaign_submission_answers`.* FROM `campaign_submission_answers`
   INNER JOIN `campaign_submissions` ON `campaign_submissions`.`id` = `campaign_submission_answers`.`campaign_submission_id`
   INNER JOIN `participants` ON `participants`.`id` = `campaign_submissions`.`participant_id`
   INNER JOIN `campaign_questions` ON `campaign_questions`.`id` = `campaign_submission_answers`.`campaign_question_id`
   INNER JOIN `campaign_question_options` ON `campaign_question_options`.`text` = `campaign_submission_answers`.`answer` 
   WHERE `campaign_submissions`.`campaign_id` = 1 AND `participants`.`appraisee_id` = 1 AND `campaign_submission_answers`.`campaign_question_id` = 1
   GROUP BY `campaign_submission_answers`.`id`
) as `csa` ON `csa`.`answer` = `campaign_question_options`.`text`
WHERE `campaign_questions`.`id` = 1
GROUP BY `campaign_question_options`.`text`;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have `left join`s and you want to filter on an any table but the first, you need to put the conditions in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT cqo.`text`, 
       COUNT(csa.`answer`) as `count`
FROM `campaign_questions` cq INNER JOIN
     `campaign_question_options` cqo 
     ON cqo.`campaign_question_id` = cq.`id` LEFT JOIN
     `campaign_submission_answers` csa
     ON csa.`answer` = cqo.`text` AND csa.`campaign_question_id` = 1 LEFT JOIN
     `campaign_submissions` cs
     ON cs.`id` = csa.`campaign_submission_id LEFT JOIN
     `participants` p
     ON p.`id` = cs.`participant_id` AND
        p. appraisee_id = XXX
WHERE cq.`id` = 1
GROUP BY csa.`answer` 
ORDER BY cqo.`index`;
```

I also added table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: I had to fiddle with the statement a bit to get the aliases correct, since it wasn't referencing the right alias on the select for the `text` column. However once I fixed this I ended up with the first result set outlined in my question.

Comment: To elaborate on the change, I had to change `co.text` to `cqo.text`

Answer (score 0):

Add another check in case `participants`.`appraisee_id` is `NULL`:

```
WHERE `campaign_questions`.`id` = 1 
  AND (`participants`.`appraisee_id` = 1 
   OR `participants`.`appraisee_id` IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is close, however it doesn't give me zero counts for all the options

    1 (positive) 16
    2 1
    5 (negative) 0